# Windows 10 Folder Structure Or Hierachy

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am a noob at all means, but somehow it is possible to imagine how Linux folder structure looks like - even without having seen one. It all starts out from the root!

But even after having used windows since 95, it is still not clear how to draw it for win 10, and if it is more of a bush than a tree. Or not like anything imaginably - after all.

Have anybody managed to draw just a sketch of Win 10 folder structure, and if so, where or how to find it? Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in command in windows called **Tree**

1. Open a Command Prompt
2. Change Folder to \
3. Type in **Tree**

You get something like this.

```
├───Drivers
│   ├───Audio
│   │   └───Realtek
│   │       ├───Config
│   │       ├───MSHDQFE
│   │       │   ├───Win2K3
│   │       │   │   └───us
│   │       │   └───Win2K_XP
│   │       │       └───us
│   │       ├───Vista
│   │       ├───Vista64
│   │       └───WDM
│   ├───Chipset
│   │   └───INFUpdate
│   │       ├───All
│   │       ├───ia64
│   │       ├───Lang
│   │       │   └───CHIP
│   │       │       ├───ARA
│
```

It is pretty huge, so you should redirect the output to a file.

Comment: That has been there since DOS 1

Comment: Yes, but only the oldies know about it

Comment: @RohitGupta, Tree is a great idea. unfortunately, on this PC, at least, it gets stuck beyond the folder `servicing`, whether output to screen or to file. WinDirStat, https://windirstat.net/, is another way to crawl the directory tree, but it, too, slows drastically, taking *many* minutes to finish, if at all. The `Windows` directory has grown so large, and is accessible in places only by TrustedInstaller or other special user,  as to be almost undecipherable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Windows folder has many folders which have no access.  No matter what you use, there will be an issue.  It's possible that with elevated access, it might go through.  But why bother?

Comment: Thank you for introducing this function. It makes sense that it is possible in windows too.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that Windows folder structure is imaginably. It is bush structured, with a kind of "head root" in C:/

As an operating system that embraces skilled as unskilled users, its paths are helpfull. But too much help had dulled my perception and moving into Linux recently, it was suddenly clear how little I knew of Windows behind the scenes mechanisms.

Linux, Mac, Windows folder structure

[image]